# Display an Expression in a human readable format

Tags: c#, expression

I'm attempting to create an Extension method that will throw an error if an Expression isn't matched

I have the following code to start with ...

```
public static void Exists<TEntityType>(this IEnumerable<TEntityType> source, Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> input) where TEntityType : class
{
    if (input is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

    var record = repository.Where(input);

    if (record == null)
    {
        // issue here ...

        throw new NotFoundException(typeof(TEntityType).FullName, string.Empty); // todo provide value
    }
}
```

I can call this code like this ...

```
records.Exists(x => x.Description == methodParameter.PropertyName);
```

This then correctly throws the NotFoundException based on the property. Unfortunately the error is not very user friendly and you can hardly tell any details about the issue. What I'd like to do is to simplify the expression into simpler terms. 
To accomplish this aim I've tried the following.

```
var compileTarget = input.Compile().Target;
```

Inside `compileTarget` are some of the values I'm looking for. In Quick Watch it looks like this

```
((System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure)compileTarget).Constants[0]
```

I can also see the values in the Immediate Window, Local variables and the variable inspector, but I can't seem to get these values into the code. Is there any way to interpret these values with the aim of translating the entire expression into human readable code?

If `methodParameter.PropertyName` is `test` then I'd be looking for something like `Description = test` or `Description is test`?

Comment: Is there something wrong with using `input.ToString()`? If you want an enduser friendly version, I think you would need to write an ExpressionVisitor.

Comment: `input.ToString()` gives me `"x => (x.Description == value(ProjectName.Namespace.FileName+<>c__DisplayClass1_0).methodParameter.PropertyName)"` I'd like the value inside of `methodParameter.PropertyName` instead of the property name. Hadn't heard of a ExpressionVisitor before tho. Will investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the start of an `ExpressionVisitor` that replaces `MemberExpression`s that reference constants with their values, assuming those only show up in evaluatable situations (really, really untested).

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    public static Expression Simplify(this Expression e) => (new SimplifyVisitor()).Visit(e);
    public static string SimplifiedString(this LambdaExpression e) => e.Body.Simplify().ToString();
}

public class SimplifyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node) {
        if (node.Expression is ConstantExpression)
            return Expression.Constant(Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(node, typeof(object))).Compile().Invoke(), node.Type);
        else
            return node;
    }
}
```

With these defined, you could use

```
throw new NotFoundException(typeof(TEntityType).FullName, input.SimplifiedString());
```

NOTE: If you are willing to use `DynamicInvoke` you can avoid the cast in the visitor:

```
return Expression.Constant(Expression.Lambda(node).Compile().DynamicInvoke(), node.Type);
```